# Switch off event in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In my WP8 application i want to clear all pinned tiles of my app before the phone is going to switch off. Is there any event which will fire when the phone begin to switch off?

Comment: I do not think userland applications have access to system level events. Take a look at [`PhoneApplicationService Events`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff708099.aspx). Specifically `Closing` and `Deactivated`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only events you can react to are `Closing` and `Deactivated`.

No events are fired in your application when the phone switches of.